# How can I to parse all html code with python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse a part of HTML from a site with authorization.
But when I try to do it, my script can't find all tags
this part :

```
<tbody>              
    <td class="ng-binding">name</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">name</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">name</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">name</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><!-- end ngIf: bsks -->
<!-- ngIf: (bsks | size)>0 --><tr class="bsstr ng-scope" ng-if="(bsks | size)>0">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><b class="ng-binding">сумма</b></td>
    <td></td>
</tr><!-- end ngIf: (bsks | size)>0 -->
<!-- ngIf: (bsks | size) === 0 -->
<!-- ngRepeat: item in bsks | orderBy: date --><!-- ngIf: (bsks | size) > 0 --><tr class="bsstr ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in bsks | orderBy: date" ng-if="(bsks | size) > 0">
    <td>
```

I am a beginner , please help me to parse this part of cite
How can I get all tags that I need?
The site has another page for authorization (  `url = self.BASE_URL + 'api/v1/login/auth?info=1'`)

```
class Auth:
    BASE_URL = 'http.............'

    def auth(self):
        params = {
            'user': u'g1625719',
            'pass': u'472001',
            'from_site': 1,
            'dev': u'16e753be3dc097354e3328e47c3701a9'
        }
        session = requests.Session()
        url = self.BASE_URL + 'api/v1/login/auth?info=1'
        r = session.post(url, params)
        print(r.text)

    def get_url(self):
        url = self.BASE_URL + '#!/line/cart/checklist/'
        print(url)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return response.read()

    def parse(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.get_url(), 'html.parser')
        table = soup.body.find('div', {'class': 'example-animate-container'})
        print(table)
```

It is work incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using find_all (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree)

```
class Auth:
    BASE_URL = 'http.............'

    def auth(self):
        params = {
            'user': u'g1625719',
            'pass': u'472001',
            'from_site': 1,
            'dev': u'16e753be3dc097354e3328e47c3701a9'
        }
        session = requests.Session()
        url = self.BASE_URL + 'api/v1/login/auth?info=1'
        r = session.post(url, params)
        print(r.text)

    def get_url(self):
        url = self.BASE_URL + '#!/line/cart/checklist/'
        print(url)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return response.read()

    def parse(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.get_url(), 'html.parser')
        table = soup.body.find_all('div', {'class': 'example-animate-container'})
        print(table)
```